# SQL Connection Error

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error while trying to access my website:

```
Exception information:

Exception type: SqlException
```

> Exception message: An error has occurred while establishing a
>   connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this
>   failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL
>   Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

This error occurs 6-7 times in a whole day.

Can anyone tell me why do I am getting this error? Is there any special settings I can made on my SQL server end to avoid this crash or its a problem in my web application?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your connection string (without password/username ofcourse.)

Comment: If your connection usually works and only sometimes it doesn't, I can think about network problems (example for heavy traffic) or high load on server that doesn't make it respond to a new connection attempt.

Comment: may be your website is accessing the DB in a loop that makes the DB much busy that it will be not available for some time and throws this type of error. for this you should look at the usage of db

Comment: @JLevett:
data source=[SERVERADDRESS];initial catalog=[DBNAME];user id=[USER];password=[PASSWORD];persist security info=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000;Connection Lifetime=30;

Comment: One thing interesting, i am using SQL SERver 2008 but in an error message its showing 2005. 

In addition, we are using SSIS packages on the server for some updates and they are scheduled via SQL SErver Agent. Can they create any trouble in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

If this problem only occurs only from time to time, it's likely you are running into a timeout for one (or more) of your commands.

Try increasing the value of the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property of your commands.

Also try profiling your Sql server for longrunning queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to configure your SQL server 2005 to allow remote connections: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by various things:

- remote connection disabled in SQL Server.
- Firewall settings
- bad connection string

This KB-Article of Microsoft might help... http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277

EDIT: Be aware that if you develop on a system that has a local database the data is exchanged normally over shared memory. Where as in test- and production-environments you have a separate database server that has to be connected over the tcp protocol with you application.

ConnectionString:

> data source=[SERVERADDRESS];initial catalog=[DBNAME];user
>   id=[USER];password=[PASSWORD];persist security
>   info=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000;Connection Lifetime=30;

Do you really have to set the pool size and connection lifetime? I am rarely using this settings. They might cause the trouble. Specially the

> Connection Lifetime

Should be used very carefully. Read more here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2004/09/20/231963.aspx